# add controls to ajax update panel programatically on click of a button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i want to add a label to update panel, on button click..
i have following code in .aspx file...

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >
                   <ContentTemplate >
                       <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPanel" >
                        <label id="ssd" runat="server" >abc</label>
                       </asp:Panel>
                       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click"  Text="test"/>
                   </ContentTemplate>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and on button click event..

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label l1 = new Label();
    l1.ID = "label1";
    l1.Text = "this is it...";
    up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(l1);      
}
```

but its not working ..:-(

Answer (score 1):

Since the `UpdatePanel`'s UpdateMode is set to `Conditional`, you need to update it manually from codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label l1 = new Label();
    l1.ID = "label1";
    l1.Text = "this is it...";
    up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(l1); 

    up.Update();     
}
```

MSDN [**`UpdatePanel.Update`** Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx)

> If you plan to use the Update method, set the UpdateMode property to
>   Conditional. If you want the decision to update the panel in server
>   logic, make sure that the ChildrenAsTriggers property is false and
>   that no explicit triggers are defined for the panel.
>
> In a typical page development scenario, if you define triggers or if
>   the ChildrenAsTriggers property is true for the UpdatePanel control,
>   the Update method is automatically called during the page life cycle.

Note that you need to recreate dynamical controls even with ASP.NET Ajax. So you need to create the label manually on the next postback in `page_load` at the latest.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label l1 = new Label();
        l1.ID = "label1";
        l1.Text = "this is it...";
        this.form1.Controls.Add(l1);
    } even this is not adding label to my page :-(